# How to create an empty File Object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

Creating an empty `File` object in JavaScript like this is supported in Chome but not in IE 11.

```
var file=new File([""],"fileName");
```

Is there a way which is compatible with IE 11?

Comment: IE does not support File constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Browser_compatibility

Comment: What do you want to do with this File? The only API requiring such an object ([*DataTransferItemList#add*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItemList/add)) is not supported by IE anyway.